# Problems connecting .net app frontend to api docker container, certificate problem

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, certificate

The application is developed in .net 6 and docker, I can connect from frontend container to api container with `curl -k  https://booksapi/api/book`

without the -k the result is

```
curl: (77) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain wa
s issued by an authority that is not trusted.
```

The result in the application call to the API:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)

HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync<TIOAdapter>(TIOAdapter adapter, bool receiveFirst, byte[] reAuthenticationData, bool isApm)
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Show raw exception details
HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()........
```

The call to the API:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details()
{
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Author");
    var response = await client.GetAsync($"api/authors/");
    var allAuthors = await response.ReadContentAs<List<Author>>();
    return View(allAuthors);
}
```

I get the error on `var response = await client.GetAsync($"api/authors/")`

The error on the container:

```
{"EventId":1,"LogLevel":"Error","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware","Message":"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.","Exception":"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.  ---\u003E System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation\u00601.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.\u003CSendAsync\u003Eg__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)    at BookMemoriesFrontend.Controllers.AuthorController.Details() in C:\\src\\Frontend\\BookMemoriesFrontend\\Controllers\\AuthorController.cs:line 44    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.\u003CInvokeActionMethodAsync\u003Eg__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask\u00601 actionResultValueTask)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.\u003CInvokeNextActionFilterAsync\u003Eg__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State\u0026 next, Scope\u0026 scope, Object\u0026 state, Boolean\u0026 isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.\u003CInvokeInnerFilterAsync\u003Eg__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.\u003CInvokeNextResourceFilter\u003Eg__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State\u0026 next, Scope\u0026 scope, Object\u0026 state, Boolean\u0026 isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.\u003CInvokeFilterPipelineAsync\u003Eg__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.\u003CInvokeAsync\u003Eg__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.\u003CInvokeAsync\u003Eg__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.\u003CInvoke\u003Eg__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)","State":{"Message":"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.","{OriginalFormat}":"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request."}}
```

All of this works if i don't use docker.

Thanks for the help in advance, it has been a hard work to connect API.